# Regions do not display in "Demonstrate block regions"

Tags: theming

I wonder why some regions of my theme don't display in section 'Demonstrate block rerions'.

This happens with some themes which I downloaded from Drupal.org, for example with the [Software](https://www.drupal.org/project/software_responsive_theme) theme.

Here is part of its 'info' file (showing multiple regions):

[image]

And this is what 'Demonstrate block rerions' for this theme looks like:

[image]

**My question**: What could be causing this?

I use SEVEN as admin theme. On page admin/structure/block I see the link  "Demonstrate block regions (Software Responsive Theme)" and all regions that defined in .info file. But when I click this link, I see ONLY SOME OF IT BUT NOT ALL .
I try to change admin theme, but it is not help.

Maybe problem in this particular theme?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the administration theme you're using, to a theme shipped with Drupal core.

Or refer to the article ["Demonstrate block regions" missing in Drupal 7](http://drupal7notes.tumblr.com/post/14249345867/demonstrate-block-regions-missing-in-drupal-7) for some more hints about this. Here are some quotes from it:

> On a fresh install, you should see "Demonstrate block regions" when you go to admin/structure/block.  If somebody has played around with the block settings on your Admin theme, this selection might disappear.
>
> Make sure that “System help” is assigned to a region (probably ‘Help’) in your Admin theme (probably 'Seven’).  Go to 'configure’ for the 'System help’ block and make sure that the visibility settings are not restricted in some way.

Another possibilities you may want to try (haven't had a chance myself to try that, sorry):

- inspired by [Issue # 996214](https://www.drupal.org/node/996214), which is about another theme though:

  > Verify if the "System Help" block is placed in the help region.
- inspired by [Issue # 1392206](https://www.drupal.org/node/1392206#comment-5740832), which is about another theme though:

  > You might need to **turn on the Help module** in core modules.

Comment: it doesn't help . (:

Comment: Thanks for the edit of your question. From your "PS" in the question, I seem to understand "it works if I use SEVEN as admin theme, is that a correct interpretion? If so then re-edit the question to explain what "it doesn't help" actualy means (maybe something like 'it works if I use Seven as admin theme, but NOT if I use 'some other' (= which one?) theme" ...

Comment: I try all decision from this article - nothing to help (:

Comment: I found answer for my question.
In demonstrate block region page - we can see only regioins, which present in all page of the site.

If , for examle, some regions are displayed depending on certain conditions - they do not shows on demonstate page.

For exapmle:
<?php if ($is_front): ?>
  <?php print render($page['slideshow']); ?>
<?endif; ?>
The slideshow regions will not be shown on demonstate regions page.